# Thrust: synchronize: launch_closure_by_value: unknown error

Tags: thrust

I am experimenting with Thrust example monte-carlo.ru from here:
https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/monte_carlo.cu .
The problem appears in this peace of code:

```
    float estimate = thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0),
            thrust::counting_iterator<int>(M),
            estimate_pi(),
            0.0f,
            thrust::plus<float>());
```

When I increase length of input sequence to more than M=87000 for transform_reduce method I got an error:
"synchronize: launch_closure_by_value: unknown error"

Just before the error the screen is became black for several seconds, then in systray I see a message "The video driver NVidia stopped responding and was successfully restored" (my back translation) and then I reboot my computer because it's behavior is unstable.

When I try to use cuda-memcheck the situation is changed: I got the same error already for length M=30000 although when running .exe without cuda-memcheck the program ends successfully for this length.

Here is several lines from cuda-memcheck output:

```
========= Program hit cudaErrorUnknown (error 30) due to "unknown error" on CUDA API call to cudaThreadSynchronize. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\nvcuda.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0xc2d92) [0xe06b2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\cudart64_65.dll (cudaThreadSynchronize + 0xf5) [0x19585]
=========     Host Frame:C:\test\Monte_carlo.exe (thrust::system::cuda::detail::synchronize + 0x47) [0x11117]
...  
========= Program hit cudaErrorUnknown (error 30) due to "unknown error" on CUDA API call to cudaFree. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:C:\Windows\system32\nvcuda.dll (cuProfilerStop + 0xc2d92) [0xe06b2]
=========     Host Frame:C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.5\bin\cudart64_65.dll (cudaFree + 0xfd) [0x1d28d]
=========     Host Frame:C:\test\Monte_carlo.exe (thrust::system::cuda::detail::free > + 0x50) [0x5fa0]
```

Below also full code of the program. I added to the original only 2 changes: try-catch around transform_reduce and input M from console.
How can I understand the reason of this error?

```
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

// we could vary M & N to find the perf sweet spot

__host__ __device__
unsigned int hash(unsigned int a)
{
    a = (a+0x7ed55d16) + (a<<12);
    a = (a^0xc761c23c) ^ (a>>19);
    a = (a+0x165667b1) + (a<<5);
    a = (a+0xd3a2646c) ^ (a<<9);
    a = (a+0xfd7046c5) + (a<<3);
    a = (a^0xb55a4f09) ^ (a>>16);
    return a;
}

struct estimate_pi : public thrust::unary_function<unsigned int,float>
{
  __host__ __device__
  float operator()(unsigned int thread_id)
  {
    float sum = 0;
    unsigned int N = 10000; // samples per thread

    unsigned int seed = hash(thread_id);

    // seed a random number generator
    thrust::default_random_engine rng(seed);

    // create a mapping from random numbers to [0,1)
    thrust::uniform_real_distribution<float> u01(0,1);

    // take N samples in a quarter circle
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
      // draw a sample from the unit square
      float x = u01(rng);
      float y = u01(rng);

      // measure distance from the origin
      float dist = sqrtf(x*x + y*y);

      // add 1.0f if (u0,u1) is inside the quarter circle
      if(dist <= 1.0f)
        sum += 1.0f;
    }

    // multiply by 4 to get the area of the whole circle
    sum *= 4.0f;

    // divide by N
    return sum / N;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  // use 30K independent seeds
  int M;

    std::cout << "M: ";
    std::cin >> M;
    try
    {
        float estimate = thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::counting_iterator<int>(0),
                                thrust::counting_iterator<int>(M),
                                estimate_pi(),
                                0.0f,
                                thrust::plus<float>());
        estimate /= M;

        std::cout << "M = " << std::setw(6) << M << "  " << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(6);
        std::cout << "pi is approximately " << estimate << std::endl;
    }

    catch (thrust::system_error &e)   
    {
        // output an error message and exit
        std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are running on windows and are running into a WDDM TDR watchdog timeout.  The windows OS detects that your GPU is busy for too long and resets the GPU driver.  After the reset you get the unknown error.  This problem is widely discussed on SO, you will find many references to it. You can start by reading [this](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Timeout_Detection_Recovery.htm)

Comment: Thank you for help - now I understand the problem (I am new in CUDA programming). But does it mean that Thrust (in particular, transform_reduce method) can't be used directly for very long input sequences (M=1 000 000)? And I should invent my own (manual)procedure for this, for example by dividing long sequences into shorter parts?

Comment: I would say that you should run on a system that does not have a watchdog.  Or else disable the watchdog.  Thrust can be used with large data.